# Preparing Injection Hibernate Session and Transaction process: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, struts2

```
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Preparing Injection Hibernate Session and Transaction process: /userLoginAction - Method: idsspl.erp.global.action.LoginAction.listUser() 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: No Hibernate Session in current thread. New Hibernate Session will be created and returned (SessionFactory "(default)") 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: New Hibernate Session required - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: New Hibernate Session created and returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "idsspl.erp.global.action.LoginAction" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Existing Hibernate Session from current thread returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "idsspl.erp.global.dao.ProgramMasterDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Existing Hibernate Session from current thread returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "idsspl.erp.administration.dao.UserCreationDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Existing Hibernate Session from current thread returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "idsspl.erp.administration.dao.CompanyCreationDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Existing Hibernate Session from current thread returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "idsspl.erp.accounting.dao.VoucherMasterDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Existing Hibernate Session from current thread returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "idsspl.erp.global.dao.LoginDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session Required (from current Thread) - SessionFactory required: (default) 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Existing Hibernate Session from current thread returned (SessionFactory "") 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session from Full Hibernate Plugin's Hibernate Session Factory 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Session injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "session". Class "idsspl.erp.global.setget.Login" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transaction injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "transaction". Class "idsspl.erp.global.action.LoginAction" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transaction injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "transaction". Class "idsspl.erp.administration.dao.UserCreationDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transaction injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "transaction". Class "idsspl.erp.administration.dao.CompanyCreationDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transaction injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "transaction". Class "idsspl.erp.accounting.dao.VoucherMasterDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transaction injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "transaction". Class "idsspl.erp.global.dao.LoginDAO" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Hibernate Transaction injected (by annotation) into Action. Field "transaction". Class "idsspl.erp.global.setget.Login" 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin Validation in class idsspl.erp.global.action.LoginAction 
17:24:08 - DEBUG: Full Hibernate Plugin Validation found no erros. 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at idsspl.erp.global.action.EncodingEncryptionDecryption.encrypt(EncodingEncryptionDecryption.java:101)
    at idsspl.erp.global.dao.LoginDAO.lisrUserDAO(LoginDAO.java:38)
    at idsspl.erp.global.action.LoginAction.listUser(LoginAction.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.s2hibernatevalidator.interceptor.HibernateValidatorInterceptor.intercept(HibernateValidatorInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.intercept(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: Your question formation is not good..

Comment: Could you add some explanation please? People will need some context to help you solve your problem ;-)

Comment: Hibernate session and transaction could be injected, even if managed with Spring.